# Linq to SQL specflow, Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<'

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, specflow

I'm using a linq to sql query in spec flow, and I need to pass the results of my query to a Private Field in the Binding Class so I can access it in later step files, but everything I try runs my into the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`

The final query will contain 15 - 20 variables.  Any thoughts on how to define my Private Field in the Binding Class?

```
public class Member_Dim_OrganizationsSteps
{

    connectionDataContext cMain = new connectionDataContext();

    static private List<string> mainString;

    [Given(@"I have selected the MemberOrganizations field values from MemberOrganizations")]
    public void GivenIHaveSelectedTheMemberOrganizationsFieldValuesFromMemberOrganizations()
    {

        var mainResults = (from mo in oecMain.MemberOrganizations
                              orderby mo.OrgID
                              select new
                              {
                                  OrgID = (mo.OrgID),
                                  OrgKey = (mo.OrgKey != null ? mo.OrgKey : "").Trim().ToUpper(),
                                  BaseOrgKey = (mo.OrgKey != null ? mo.OrgKey.Substring(0, 11) : "-----").ToUpper(),
                                  ManufacturerID = (Convert.ToInt16(mo.ManufacturerID != null ? mo.ManufacturerID : 0)),
                              });


        mainString = mainResults.ToList();


    }
```

Comment: You're trying to convert a list of an anonymous type with multiple fields to a list of strings.  How do expect that conversion to happen implicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the results of the query around, then you need to define a concrete type instead of using an anonymous type:

```
public class Result
{
    public int OrgID {get; set;}
    public string OrgKey {get; set;}
    public string BaseOrgKey {get; set;}
    public int ManufacturerID {get; set;}
}
```

use that type for your list type"

```
private List<Result> mainString;
```

then project to that type in your query:

```
var mainResults = (from mo in oecMain.MemberOrganizations
                   orderby mo.OrgID
                   select new Result
                   {
                     OrgID = (mo.OrgID),
                     OrgKey = (mo.OrgKey != null ? mo.OrgKey : "").Trim().ToUpper(),
                     BaseOrgKey = (mo.OrgKey != null ? mo.OrgKey.Substring(0, 11) : "-----").ToUpper(),
                     ManufacturerID = (Convert.ToInt16(mo.ManufacturerID != null ? mo.ManufacturerID : 0)),
                   });
```

Comment: Thanks!  Great stuff.  As soon as I add 'Result' to 'select new Result' , I get the error message "'Result.OrgKey' is inaccessible due to its protection level."  (same for all) Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @Richard I forgot to make the properties `public`.  Class members are `private` by default.

Comment: @D Stanley - Thank you!  Worked perfectly !